# Removing everything after a char in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have the following dataframe 'countries':

```
  country      info
 england       london-europe
 scotland      edinburgh-europe
 china         beijing-asia
 unitedstates  washington-north_america
```

I would like to take the info field and have to remove everything after the '-', to become:

```
 country      info
 england       london
 scotland      edinburgh
 china         beijing
 unitedstates  washington
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the string and grabbing the first part? Or using regex? Hint: `df.apply` could work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
countries['info'] = countries['info'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

Output:

```
     country        info
0       england      london
1      scotland   edinburgh
2         china     beijing
3  unitedstates  washington
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to keep the first part of the string after a split on the dash character:

```
countries['info'] = countries['info'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

Or, equivalently, you can use

```
countries['info'] = countries['info'].str.split('-').map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: @ScottBoston Yeah, well deserved, upvote for you haha

Comment: I would avoid assigning column values via the dot-accessor and this is a perfect dxample why. `DataFrame.info()` is a method that displays information about all of the columns in the dataframe.

Comment: I agree with @PaulH.  I decide long ago to always use the quote notation over using the "shortcut" dot notation due to limitations with the dot notation.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `str.extract` with pattern `r"(\w+)(?=\-)"`

**Ex:**

```
print(df['info'].str.extract(r"(\w+)(?=\-)"))
```

**Output:**

```
         info
0      london
1   edinburgh
2     beijing
3  washington
```